# Selenium Grid - Remote Controls always being unregistered by hub

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I have Selenium Grid 1.0.8 running well  with the hub and several remote controls on the same machine.   My testNG tests all run  successfully.

When I start a remote control on a different machine, everything initially appears to be fine.   The hub console shows the remote control to be available with the default environment "*firefox".

However, when I run the tests (still on the hub machine), the remote controls on the other box never work properly.    They keep getting deregistered from the hub.

I've disabled the firewalls and I can ping betweeen the two boxes.   Has anyone encountered similar issues?

The Remote Control Log:

[java] 21:34:19.479 WARN - Hub at http://192.168.1.129:4444/heartbeat?host=localhost&port=5539 does not have us as registered
     [java] 21:34:49.496 INFO - Checking connection to hub...
     [java] 21:34:49.496 INFO - Ping Hub at http://192.168.1.129:4444/heartbeat?host=localhost&port=5539

The hub log:

[java] INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions...

```
 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry

 [java] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused

 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry

 [java] INFO: Retrying request
 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
 [java] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
 [java] INFO: Retrying request
 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
 [java] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
 [java] Jun 16, 2011 9:39:52 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
 [java] INFO: Retrying request
```

Comment: I have seen this same issue reported by many people.One of them said it was due to the network. Search in seleniumusers googlegroups you will find the answer in one of the threads.

Comment: Thanks Nirvdrum, what you described was the problem with my setup.  I discovered it previously after doing a few more tests with the hub and RCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing the correct host value when you register your node?  In order to deal with proxies properly, the node must provide a routable hostname to that **node** when registering with the hub.  Without this value, the hub will be unable to communicate with the node and will unregister it.